# How to stop page refresh using Javascript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, wordpress

I tried multiple ways to stop the page but unfortunately, it won't work, I have one frontend form of Wordpress Plugin 
i try may time but code not worked
Plugin form code

```
echo '<div id="submit_car_form">';
echo '<form id="cd_car" name="cd_car" class="cd_car" method="post" action="'.$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'].'" enctype="multipart/form-data" >';

        echo '<input type="hidden" name="author_id" value="'. get_current_user_id().' " />';

        echo '<p><label for="title">Title</label><br />';
        echo '<input type="text" id="title" value="" size="60" name="title" />';
        echo '</p>';

       ..........................
       i Have multiple inputs
       ..........................

        echo '<p align="left"><input type="submit" tabindex="6" id="submit_car" name="submit_car" /></p>';
        wp_nonce_field( "car-frontend-post" );
        echo '</form>';
        echo '</div>';
```

Javascript Code for Stop refresh on form Submit

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $('#submit_car').on('submit', function(event){
    // $('#cd_car').on('submit', function(e){
    // $('#cd_car').submit(function(e){
    // $('#submit_car').click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var message = document.getElementById("file").value;
        var title = document.forms["cd_car"]["title"].value;
        if (title == ""){
            alert("Title cannot be empty");
            return false;
        }
        else {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST', 
            dataType: 'JSON',
            data: new FormData($('#car_data')[0]),
            contentType: false,
            cache: false,
            processData: false,
            success: function(data){
                console.log(data);
                alert('Your Form Submited');
            },
            error: function(data){
                console.log(data);
                alert('something wrong');
            }
        });
        return false;
      }
  });
});
```

Comment: There's two problems here. Firstly, you use `e.preventDefault`, yet you named the argument `event` instead. Change to `event.preventDefault` and your code will work as you require. Secondly if you're listening for the `submit` event you should select the `#cd_car` form, not the button. Finally you can remove the `return` statements as they're moot given the use of `preventDefault()`. Voting to close as a typographical error

Comment: i correct the changes as u mention above but it display error alert message  `alert('something wrong');`

Comment: That means your AJAX request failed due to an error on the server. Also note that you seem to be missing a `url` property in the AJAX request

Comment: yes just now i add url ` url : '<?php echo admin_url("admin-ajax.php"); ?>';`

Answer (score 1):

Your form has an id of `cd_car`, not `submit_car`! Therefore, your JS handler will not target it until you change the selector.

Also, as mentioned in the comments, your event object in your handler is called `event`, but in your code you are using `e.preventDefault()` instead of `event.preventDefault()`

Comment: Should be "using `event.preventDefault()` instead of `e.preventDefault()`"

Comment: @GrumpysaysReinstateMonica I was saying that OP is using `e` instead of `event`, and not the opposite.

Comment: Sorry, I read it as "you _should_ be using" for some reason.

Comment: yes, I change event argument and pass the id of function that is '#car_data' so not shows alert error message alert('something wrong');